# Extract image sequence with only 1 color chanel out of rgb avi movie with VirtualDub

Tags: virtualdub

I have an uncompressed RGB AVI file which containes 10 greyscale images: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9wKP6yNcpyfY1JzdmJTcHhjTmM (10 images)

With VirtualDub I would like to extract the images whicht should have only 1 channel. I all cases that I tried the images have always 3 channels.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do this often your option is "export via external encoder" with VirtualDub FilterMod https://sourceforge.net/projects/vdfiltermod
(rgb export was not possible with official VirtualDub)

the preset below will save gray tiff sequence using ffmpeg (download ffmpeg.exe and replace path to it)

```
{
    "description": "VirtualDub external encoder profile collection",
    "externalEncoders": {
        "sets": {
            "tiff_gray": {
                "videoEncoder": "tiff_gray",
                "audioEncoder": "",
                "multiplexer": "",
                "description": "",
                "extension": "",
                "processPartial": false,
                "useOutputAsTemp": true
            }
        },
        "profiles": {
            "tiff_gray": {
                "name": "tiff_gray",
                "program": "E:\\download\\vd\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe",
                "commandArguments": "-f rawvideo -pix_fmt %(pix_fmt) -s %(width)x%(height) -r %(fpsnum)/%(fpsden) -i - -pix_fmt gray8 %(tempvideofile)_%%04d.tif",
                "outputFilename": "",
                "type": 0,
                "pixelFormat": "bgra",
                "inputFormat": 0,
                "checkReturnCode": true,
                "logStdout": true,
                "logStderr": true,
                "bypassCompression": false,
                "predeleteOutputFile": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```